# Adding dynamic web views in android

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I am going through various links on this topic. I haven't found anything useful in my case. I want to create a `Web View` in Android dynamically. I will add nothing onto the xml layout file. 
Now I want to do two things in particular:
 1. I want to set the size of this Web View to a custom width and height and set it at the bottom of the Layout.
 2. Once the page loads in the Web view. On click on the Web view should resize and go full screen(which means fill_parent on width and height for web view in its parent layout).

My current code looks something like this below which does not work particularly well as the full screen does not fit the content to screen:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    RelativeLayout layout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        layout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.test);

        final WebView web = new WebView(this);

        //web.setId(1);
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.loadData("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://www..myurl.com/myfolder/banner.php\"></script>", null, null);

        layout.addView(web, new LayoutParams(300,100));


        web.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                web.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                return false;
            }
        }); 
    }   
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: can you post screen shot for both scenario for better understanding?

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your problem correctly, you may want to consider the following approach.

First, declare and initialize the (parent) relative layout, together with its parameters and set it as the content view (delete setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);).

```
    final RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

    final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(),
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight());

    layout.setLayoutParams(params);

    setContentView(layout);
```

Then, initialize the web view and its parameters, and add the "bottom rule" to the parameters.

```
    final WebView web = new WebView(this);

    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.loadData(
            "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://www..myurl.com/myfolder/banner.php\"></script>",
            null, null);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams webViewParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            300, 100);
    webViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
```

Finally, add the web view to your (parent) relative layout and add its listener.

```
    layout.addView(web, webViewParams);

    web.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            web.setLayoutParams(params);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Hope this is what you needed.

Cheers!